# Panel with in Listview gives me an error(Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a panel in Itewmtemplate of list view it's only supposed to show when user is logged in, by default the visibility = false. Help is appreciated.

here is my c# code:

```
    Panel pnlOptions = (Panel)ListView1.FindControl("pnlOptions");
    pnlOptions.Visible = true;
```

Aspx Code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlOptions" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <ul>
        <ul>
        <li style="float: left">Option 1:</li>
        <li style="float: left">dropdown here</li>
        </ul>
    <li style="float: left">Option 1:</li>
    <li style="float: left">dropdwon here</li>
    </ul>

    </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because the FindControl call is either:

1. Failing - If the item is not found as a child of the control, [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) returns null.
2. Finding the "wrong" object, and the cast to `(Panel)` is failing.

I'd recommend rewriting the code as:

```
Control control = ListView1.FindControl("pnlOptions");
Panel pnlOptions = control as Panel;
pnlOptions.Visible = true;
```

You can then set breakpoints, and figure out which of the lines is failing on you.

Comment: @fzshah76: Check the type (in the debugger) of the Panel - if you rewrite as above, you should be able to figure out exactly why you're getting the problem, adn either fix it, or give us more information to help you.

Comment: No I think it's something like grid view type of thing here is another similar question http://forums.asp.net/t/1163895.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I was trying to acces it wrongly through a function I created when I was supposed to use the Item_Created Event here is the final working code:

```
protected void ListView1_ItemCreated(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    Control control = e.Item.FindControl("pnlOptions");
    Panel pnlOptions = control as Panel;
    pnlOptions.Visible = true;
}
```

Thanks Reed.

Answer (score 0):

This should work also:

```
 foreach (var item in ListView1.Items)
  {
    Panel pnlOptions = (Panel)item.FindControl("pnlOptions");
    pnlOptions.Visible = true;
  }
```